# How to change one column in 2d array by mapping function in google scripts?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, mapping

I've an array which I got from a spreadsheet by .getValues() method:

```
var arr = [
[12, 123euro, 13],
[345, 432euro, 293],
]
```

I want to remove 'eur' by mapping like this:

```
var newarr = arr.map(row => row[1].replace('euro',''))
```

But this gives me:

```
[123, 432]
```

Rewriting the line as:

```
newarr = arr.map(row => [row[0], row[1].replace('euro',''), row[2])
```

gives me the desired newarr:

```
var arr = [
[12, 123euro, 13],
[345, 432euro, 293],
]
```

I was expecting this result from the first try. What am I missing?

Comment: What is `123euro` and `432euro`? Are they strings?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, yes

Comment: In your first try you are returning a **single** element per row and that is `row[1].replace('euro','')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) expects a single return value from each iteration which is assigned to the index of that iteration in the array on which it is called.

Your first attempt `arr.map(row => row[1].replace('euro',''))` returns the return value of your [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) call, which is a string, and replaces the entire iterated `row` with it.

Instead, you want to assign that returned value back to `row[1]` and then return the entire row. (Here using a [`comma operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and converting the returned string to an integer using a [`unary plus(+)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)).

```
arr.map(row => (row[1] = +row[1].replace('euro', ''), row))
```

It should be noted that mutating the `row` array this way will also mutate the original. To avoid this you'll need to make a copy, either with [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) or by using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (or by building an entirely new array as you did in your working example).

```js
var arr = [
  [12, '123euro', 13],
  [345, '432euro', 293],
];

var newarr = arr.map(row => {
  const newRow = [...row];
  newRow[1] = +newRow[1].replace('euro', '');
  return newRow;
})

console.log(newarr);
```

Comment: That works, thank you! Can you please explain the outer parenthesis?
```(row[1] = +row[1].replace(curToken,''), row)```
and this part:
```, row```

Comment: It wraps the two expressions which are separated by the comma operator in order to implicitly return the result after all are evaluated. It is equivalent to `arr.map(row => { row[1] = +row[1].replace('euro', ''); return row; });` using a multiline callback with an explicit return value.

Comment: I want to know more about this interesting syntax. What should I search for in, say, MDN?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunc() {
  var arr = [
    [12, '123euro', 13],
    [345, '432euro', 293]
  ];
  let arr1 = arr.map((r) => {
    return [r[0], r[1].replace(/euro/g, ''), r[2]];
  });
  Logger.log(arr1);
}

Execution log
4:07:32 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:07:32 PM  Info    [[12.0, 123, 13.0], [345.0, 432, 293.0]]
4:07:32 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```